# Automatically log into osCommerce via PHP, using cURL

Tags: php, curl, oscommerce

I am working on an application which allow the customer to log into an osCommerce website to retrieve data. So far I have this script, which works fine for few other websites like Wordpress, but not for osCommerce.

```
<?php
$ch = curl_init();
// Login here
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'http://demo.oscommerce.com/login.php');
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
// Login/password
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, 'email_address=me@mail.xx&password=123456');
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, 'cookie.txt');
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
$store = curl_exec ($ch);
// Get this file
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'http://demo.oscommerce.com/account.php');
$content = curl_exec ($ch);
curl_close ($ch); 
// Show the file
echo $content;
?>
```

I don't know where could be the problem as I don't have enough experience in PHP to see it.
What should I modify in order to make this script log into website? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Ran it, works. What's your error?

Comment: It just gives me a blank page. If I echo the page index.php, then it shows me the page, but the user is still not logged in.

Comment: You're using a valid account login right?

Answer (score 0):

oscommerce takes "username" and not "email_address" as long as I know - unless you change the name of FORM field.  Try passing usename instead of email_address.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but it seems osCommerce have email_address. I double checked the fields.

Answer (score 0):

You have to send curl to http://demo.oscommerce.com/login.php**?action=process** instead of http://demo.oscommerce.com/login.php to go directly to check the variables

Comment: No change. It gives me a blank page as the user is not logged in. I saw there is a hidden input called "formid", I put it among username and password, but still, no effect.

Comment: i have test it in my online oscommerce and it works well email_address=me@mail.xx&password=123456 are not a valid user-pass in demo.oscommerce.com ...

Comment: maybe your server have "open external urls" to false, if yes curl can't open http://demo.oscommerce.com/login.php?action=process

Comment: I understand, but I can use this script to log into Wordpress, and it works well! Also, it's the same thing on localhost. Ah, I changed the email_address only for demo purpose. On my test I use valid user&pass. But still, I can't understand why it doesn't work? @Pablo, you test the code I wrote in the topic with no changes, except user&pass? LATER EDIT: In cookie.txt is auto-written this: # Netscape HTTP Cookie File
# http://curl.haxx.se/rfc/cookie_spec.html
# This file was generated by libcurl! Edit at your own risk.
demo.oscommerce.com FALSE / FALSE 0 osCsid 43p9tvul2iujjsof40cc327gc6

Comment: I test the code with http://<myoscommercesite>/login.php?action=process and with a valid email_adress and password and it works. Have you tried in your own server?